# Mac OS or Linux - Change year but leave Month Day Hours & Seconds untouched

Tags: linux, macos, date, touch, timestamp

I need to recurse a directory tree and update the YEAR ONLY portion of the timestamp for all files to a certain year. I can't work out how to do this with touch. I can't use touch -A since the the target files have many different years so relative adjustment is out.

I simply want to update all years to 2013 regardless of what they currently are but need to leave the rest of the time stamp untouched. Is this possible?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

#This is to ensure that the output of all the commands will be in english
export LANG=C

#Gets the modification date from the file, you can change it to get any other timestamp instead.
MODDATE=$(stat $1 | fgrep Modify | cut -d" " -f2)

YEAR=2013

#Sets month and day as the old date
MONTH=$(echo $MODDATE | cut -d- -f2)
DAY=$(echo $MODDATE | cut -d- -f3)

NEWDATE=$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY

#Sets the new date
touch -d $NEWDATE $1
```